# Java Network Simulation

Tags: java, network-programming, omnet++

Firstly I am newbie for network simulation. And I would like to learn that I have coded a client-server program in java and they communicate with each other via asymmetric key crypto (DH), I have collect data about the time that takes to encrypt/decrypt data on client or server and time that takes between client and server to communicate.

Now, I would like to simulate this client-server socket program on a network simulator. But this time I will have many nodes(client) and one mobile server that will collect data from nodes once at a time.

Is there any way to simulate this scenario. I mean any program to run my jar files(one for client, one for server).

I googled and figured out that there are omnet++, jist/swans but i could not figure out how to use them.

Comment: use sockets. there are many tutorials out there

Comment: @PhilippSander I have already used sockets to pragram my client and server now I wanna use them on a network simulation. If you mean something different pls let me know.

Comment: @HayriCan look at the default scenarios in OMNeT, there should be something helping your case